# How to mount two devices(flashdrive) to different mount points?

Tags: filesystems, mount, corruption

I have two flash drives(/dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb1). /dev/sda1 is mounted on /mnt/RedFlashDrive while /dev/sdb1 is mounted on /mnt/TorrentDrive. When I use 
the command "ls /mnt" I got an error:

> ```
> ls: cannot access '/mnt/TorrentDrive': Transport endpoint is not connected
> ```

I cant access /mnt/TorrentDrive "inode/x-corrupted-type" but /mnt/RedFlashDrive is accessible

Comment: umount and fsck, no?

Comment: when i umount /dev/sda1 from /mnt/RedFlashDrive and mount /dev/sdb1 on /mnt/TorrentDrive. /mnt/TorrentDrive is now accessible  but the cant access the other drive "inode/x-corrupted-type"(/mnt/RedFlashDrive) when i use "ls /mnt"     Sorry for the bad english, this is my first time asking question

Comment: after unmouning it, then run `fsck -fy /dev/sdX1` on it, simple as that it should be